# How to properly nest inquirer prompts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, inquirerjs

### Summary

I'm working on a project for school that requires us to use Inquirer to help users navigate an SQL database. I've boiled down my question to a minimum example.

Basically, my main `init()` function continuously loops through an Inquirer prompt asking them what they want to do. I take their response, plug it into a `switch` statement, and perform the correct action based on the user's choice. Easy.

But then when I try to again await the call from the second prompt, the main "action" prompt actually triggers again, where the prompts are populating each other within the console. I don't really know how to describe it, but it's not what I expect.

### Code

```js
import inquirer from "inquirer";

import { employeeQuestions } from "./lib/questions.js";

const prompt = inquirer.prompt;

const actionQuestions = [{
    name: "action",
    type: "list",
    message: "Welcome! What would you like to do?",
    choices: [
        "View all Employees",
        "Add an Employee",
        "Exit"
    ]
}];

// This function handles the action chosen by the user in the main loop
const performAction = async (action) => {
    switch (action) {
        case "View all Employees":
            console.log("Not yet implmented...");
            break;
        // HERE IS WHERE THINGS BREAK DOWN
        case "Add an Employee":
            let employeeData = await prompt(employeeQuestions); // Grab the employee data by awaiting prompt
            console.log(employeeData); // Console out the data
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

// Main logic flow
 const init = async () => {
    let action;

    // While the user has not chosen to exit...
    while (action != "Exit") {
        action = (await prompt(actionQuestions)).action; // Get their choice by awaiting a prompt
        performAction(action); // Perform that chosen action
    }
}

init();
```

#### Expectation:

I would expect the program to pause at `let employeeData = await prompt(employeeQuestions);` and not proceed in that switch/case block until the user has responded.

#### Observation:

Instead, both prompts begin running at the same time.

#### Moving forward

- `View all Employees` (and similar cases left out for simplicity) would select data from SQL and display a table, but we're also asked to implement the ability to view as sorted by different columns, which would be an additional inquirer call.
- `Add an Employee` (and similar cases left out for simplicity) would need to perform SQL queries then to make those changes to the database, which not only sometimes necessitate an additional inquirer call for the relevant information but also somethings multiple SQL calls in order to correctly handle the data.

#### Conclusion

I'm missing something obvious about promises / async/await. I'm in a coding BootCamp that makes use of Inquirer repeatedly, and I get stuck in the same place every time. Please send help, or at least caffeine.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I'm not late, I will try to enlighten you as much as possible on the easiest and most effecient way to use `inquirer` (at the least for me).

So first of all i like to organize all of my questions in one file, so i don't think you would need to have to separate files filled with questions (hence `employeeQuestions`) <-- this will distract you when u need to find a specific quesiton.
Here's a sample of my questions.js:

```
const inquirer              = require('inquirer');
inquirer.registerPrompt('search-list', require('inquirer-search-list'));

module.exports = () => {
    return {
        redisURIQuestion : () => {
            const question = [
                {
                    name: 'redisURI',
                    type: "input",
                    message: 'Enter your Redis URI:',
                    default: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
                }
            ]
            return inquirer.prompt(question)
        
        },

        cortexPrefixQuestion : () => {
            const question = [
                {
                    name: 'cortexPrefix',
                    type: "input",
                    message: 'Enter your Cortex Prefix:',
                    default: 'none'
                }
            ]
            return inquirer.prompt(question)
        
        },
    }
```

Now all you need is just refernce the question you want to use:

```
const questions             = require('./questions')()

const { redisURI }      = await questions.redisURIQuestion()
const { cortexPrefix }  = await questions.cortexPrefixQuestion()
```

and of course you can use the output with conditionals if you need to check something first:

```
const { operationMode } = await questions.operationModeQuestion()

if(operationMode === 0){
  const { NODE } = await questions.nodesQuestion()
} else if(operationMode === 1){
  const { HOST } = await questions.hostsQuestion()
}
```

I have been building complex CLI apps using this concept without facing any issues hopefully this was helpful.